# unbundling a file of here docs when file's directory is different from pwd

Tags: remote, cat, here-document, pwd

All,

I have a file (called, say, **bundled_file.txt**) of here docs stored in a directory, and the file looks like this:

```
cat > a.txt << 'eof'
...
...
...
'eof'
cat > b.txt << 'eof'
...
...
...
'eof'
cat > c.txt << 'eof'
...
...
...
'eof'
```

I want to ***un***-bundle this file so that the files a.txt, b.txt, and c.txt get created *in the same directory as the original bundled file above*.

Normally, I would just `cd` to this directory and run something like `csh bundled_file.txt`, but I want to execute the `csh` command ***while in*** my pwd (print working directory).

However, when doing a remote execution from my pwd, the files a.txt, b.txt, and c.txt get created ***there***. I do not want this.

And, in case you're already thinking it, I do *not* want to change the files to say something like,

```
cat > /full/file/path/a.txt << 'eof'
...
...
...
'eof'
```

Any one who can help a novice out?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's always the case then make your code `cd` to its own directory first. [*How to set current working directory to the directory of the script?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3349105/10765659)

Comment: Thanks, Kamil! Good suggestion! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer ...

Let's say the file `bundled_file.txt` is in the folder called `test` ... and let's further say that my pwd is in the directory above, meaning the parent directory of `test` ...

I found this, which works well even though it's changing the pwd, but it immediately returns to the parent directory:

In bash, something like —

```
(cd ./test && csh bundled_file.txt)
```

Doing this, files `a.txt`, `b.txt`, and `c.txt` all get created in the folder `test`, and the pwd stays unchanged outside the subshell.

Feel free to respond to this if you have a better answer.